# Add information about new host

Tags: java, maven

I have problems with project which was written by other really talented person.

I try to deploy the project to remote host with Maven

```
user@user:~/workspace/pip$ mvn -P production, partner clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

It builds seccessful without any errors and warnings.

"partner" is some short name for server machine.partner.rmm.com.

But when i want to deploy to new server partner-test.rmm.com

```
user@user:~/workspace/pip$ mvn -P production, partner-test clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true 

......
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] pip_part1 .................................... SUCCESS [4.574s]
[INFO] pip-part2 .................................... SUCCESS [3.677s]
[INFO] pip-part3 .................................... SUCCESS [5.178s]
[INFO] pip-part4 .................................... SUCCESS [3.857s]
[INFO] pip-part5 .................................... SUCCESS [0.134s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.861s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 04 11:46:24 MSK 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/285M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "partner-test" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

It builds, but writes that  partner-test doesnt exist, and its logical, so as i havent added information about what is partner-test anywhere. but There is same situation when i try to deploy with full name

```
user@user:~/workspace/pip$ mvn -P production, partner-test.rmm.com clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

pom.xml

pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.rmm.pipproject</groupId>
<artifactId>pip</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>pip-part1</module>
    <module>pip-part2</module>
    <module>pip-part3</module>
    <module>pip-part4</module>
</modules>
```

I use Eclipse Java IDE (version: Kepler) , Ubuntu 14.04 , maven 1.7.0_65, ant 1.9.3 .

What i should do? Where do add information about partner-test?

p.s.: i understand that i dont have enough knowledge but i try to know more and more, and i hope that you can help me. I will be thankful for any advice!

---

I want to add some notices.

---

Well, I talked my goal is to deploy the project to remote host with Maven and Ant. 
According to advice of [andih](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317117/andih) (thanks him a lot!!!) I added profiles-tag to pom.xml of project pip . It's fantastic it helped me. As a result after below commands connection was established.

```
user@user:~/workspace/pip$ mvn -P production, partner clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true 
user@user:~/workspace/pip-part1$ ant -p 
user@user:~/workspace/pip-part1$ ant print-hosts
user@user:~/workspace/pip-part1$ ant deploy -Dhost=partner-test.rmm.com
```

"partner-test" is some short name for server partner-test.rmm.com. I did it by analogy with "partner" - machine.partner.rmm.com (I dont know how it has been done).

So now pom.xml file looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rmm.pipproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>pip</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <profiles>
     <profile>
       <id>partner-test</id>
       <activation>
          <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
          <server>partner-test.rmm.com</server>
        </properties>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
    <modules>
        <module>pip-part1</module>
        <module>pip-part2</module>
        <module>pip-part3</module>
        <module>pip-part4</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Its great that it start to connect, but my goal hasn't been reached. I cant to deploy project.

```
user@user:~/workspace/pip-part1$ ant deploy -Dhost=partner-test.rmm.com
Buildfile: /home/user/workspace/pip-part1/build.xml

check-dist-directory:
is-dist-exists:    
deploy:
     [echo] start
      [scp] Connecting to partner-test.rmm.com:22
      [scp] Connecting to partner-test.rmm.com port 22
      [scp] Connection established
      ....
      [scp] Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
      [scp] Next authentication method: publickey
      [scp] Authentications that can continue: password
      [scp] Next authentication method: password
      [scp] Disconnecting from partner-test.rmm.com port 22

BUILD FAILED
```

It's obviously It can't get authentication, though I've written in build.xml file to log in by public key.

```
<target name="deploy" depends="check-dist-directory,is-dist-exists" description="deploy web application on production server">
    <echo>start</echo>
    <scp file="target/pip.war" todir="pip@${host}:/var/lib/tomcat6/pip" keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa"  verbose="true"/>
    <echo>end</echo>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you need to define a maven profile "partner-test". You can define profiles at different locations:

- Project (`pom.xml`)
- User (`%USER_HOME%/.m2/settings.xml`)
- Global (`%M2_HOME%/conf/settings.xml`)
- Profile descriptor  - a descriptor located in project basedir (`profiles.xml`)

see [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Your Project Pom may look something like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>partner-test</id>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
           <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
           <id>test-parner</id>
           <name>Corporate Repository</name>
           <url>scp://repo/test-partner....</url>
           <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
          <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
          <id>testSnap</id>
          <name>Propellors Snapshots</name>
          <url>sftp://propellers.net/maven</url>
          <layout>legacy</layout>
        </snapshotRepository>

      </distributionManagement>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

More detailed information can be found on the [POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im happy that i got feedback :)  
Im not sure fist method is better way for me, because pom.xml doesnt make clear what i should change.
I added pom.xml

Comment: Create a `profiles.xml` in your project base directory, usually the same directory as your pom. Description can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-profile/profiles.html. How such a `partner-test` profile may look like I've already posted. To fill in the missing details is up to you. I can't do that because I don't have the Informations and I can't try it out.

Comment: Without any doubts you're right, and Ive seen documentation earlier, but I dont understand fully which <tag> should be used for writing short name and full name of server.
May be smth so
 `<profile>
    <id>patner-test</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <server>patner-test.rmm.com</server>
    </properties>
  </profile>` . And this code can be added to pom.xml between tags `<project></project>`. But Eclipse highlights "<profile>".

Comment: Structure is of the pom is `<project>...<profiles><profile>...</profile></profiles></project>`. Profiles are a feature of POM 4.0. for older versions you may need to use something like the `profiles.xml`. I don't know what's the purpose of full name and short name of the server. The names are usually used for humans. In the properties you can put nearby anything you want, as long as you don't reference the keys they have no meaning for the project. I think you have to explain it in more details what you need.

Answer (score 0):

in your command

```
user@user:~/workspace/pip$ mvn -P production, partner clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

"partner" is more likely to be a profile defined in the pom.xml file.

you can edit that file and add another profile "partner-test" (copy the "partner" profile and change what you need)